# Как правльно указать путь к файлу для SQL-запроса (LOAD FILE) в Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Я получаю текстовый файл через:

```
 JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Текстовый файл", "txt");
    dialog.removeChoosableFileFilter(dialog.getFileFilter());
    dialog.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    dialog.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    dialog.setDialogTitle("Выберите текстовый файл");
    dialog.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    int ret = dialog.showDialog(null, "Открыть");
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = dialog.getSelectedFile();
        pach = file.getAbsolutePath();
    } else return;
    System.out.println(pach);
```

Последняя команда показывает:

```
D:\data\streets.txt
```

Теперь я делаю запрос:

```
try {
     querySQL = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + pach + "' INTO TABLE " + DB_NAME + "." + TABLE_NAME + ";";
     stSQL.execute(querySQL);
} catch (SQLException e) {
     ErrorMsg(e, querySQL);
     isError = true;
     break;
}
```

И мне мой ErrorMsg выдает:

```
Невозможно обработать запрос:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\data\streets.txt' INTO TABLE base2.streets;
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file 'D:datastreets.txt'for 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' command.Due to underlying IOException:
```

Куда оно убирает косые и почему вообще так происходит? При том, что если такой запрос вставить в Workbench, то запрос выполняется без ошибок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратная косая черта во многих языках является символом экранирования, отменяющим специальное действие символов идущих следом. Используется для экранирования кавычек и т.д.

Для того чтобы она не воспринималась как символ экранирования ее саму нужно экранировать или проще говоря записывать 2 раза.

Хорошим тоном при работе с SQL является обязательно экранирование всех переменных передаваемых в запрос напрямую. Например через [PreparedStatements](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Я очень редко пишу на Java, но попробую написать пример (если ошибусь, специалисты поправят).

```java
querySQL = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '?' INTO TABLE " + DB_NAME + "." + TABLE_NAME + ";";
PreparedStatement loadFile=stSQL.prepareStatement(querySQL);
loadFile.setString(1, pach);
loadFile.execute();
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно задать переменную, например: String path = "D://Data/streets.txt". Но суть в том, что пользователь должен сам, через диалог выбора файлов, указать нужный файл. И вод здесь загвоздка.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра В этом нет никакой загвоздки.  Используйте PreparedStatements всегда когда делаете запрос к БД с параметрами.

Comment: спасибо огромное, буду пробовать.